# can I have 2 windows installation in the same computer in 2 different drives with the same license?

Tags: windows-10

I have a computer with a windows 10 pro license, I am wondering if I make a new fresh install on a new drive within the same computer, I need to get a new license for that fresh instalation or the same license number should work as it is the same computer. I just need to have isolated workspaces for particular reasons

Comment: Just try it. Or ask MicroSoft.

Answer (score 1):

Legally speaking, the answer is No.
Although it might work, this is a little bit risky.

According to the
[Microsoft License Terms](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm):

> **Device**. In this agreement, “device” means a hardware system (whether physical or virtual) with an internal storage device capable of running the software. **A hardware partition or blade is considered to be a device.**

Although you cannot reuse the Windows 10 key twice on the same computer,
if you tie it to your microsoft account for digital entitlement,
you may activate and deactivate and swap your windows 10 key
between as many machines as you like, *but only one at a time*.

You can reactivate a Windows 10 key through your Microsoft account.
It will only be able to activate on one installation at a time.

It could get rather messy deactivating and activating twice a day,
to stay within the legal limits.

Comment: would it work if I make a new installation on the same drive but on a different partition then?

Comment: It would probably work, but not legally. Each installation counts as a computer. In your case, the digital entitlement of your computer to the license will be updated twice a day, as if you changed disks twice a day on the same computer, since the rest of the hardware stays identical, and this is entirely legal. I have no idea what the Microsoft license servers do in such a case (or if they even care).

Answer (score 0):

You can install Windows 10 Pro on a different drive on the same computer and it will work. That is the same as just replacing your drive.

I am assuming you will just use one Windows system at one time and that will all work.

Activate as you go.

Comment: yes my plan is to use one windows instalation from 10 to 18 and then the other windows instalation, for other purposes as it will be used for different useres login remotely I prefer to keep it as isolated as possible. So with my current windows license I can then get a new drive then install windows and activate it with the same license number? :)

Comment: Yes, and just with one use at at time. Activate the license.